# Android and parse itemonclick using images

Tags: android, parse-platform

I having problems with the app I am trying to build.
I want to pull an image from parse.com then display it in a listView then from there I want to click on the listView and get the detail information about the picture, and the picture must also display the detailed information in another activity (activity detailedInformation).

Here is my code

```
dininglist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {


  //                ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView)   view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

            ParseObject Name = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);
            ParseObject type = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);
            ParseObject addr = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);
            ParseObject date = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);

//                ParseFile imageFile = urgentTodosAdapter.getItemView();

  //                ParseObject image = urgentTodosAdapter.getItem(position);
           // ParseFile icon = urgentTodosAdapter.getItemView(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Events.this, Event_booking.class);

            if (Name!=null && type!=null && addr!=null && date!=null )   {
    //                    && imageFile != null

                intent.putExtra("Name", Name.getString("Name"));

                intent.putExtra("Type", type.getString("Type"));

                intent.putExtra("Address", addr.getString("Address"));

                intent.putExtra("Date", date.getDate("Date").toString());

            //   intent.setParseFile(imageFile);


  //                    todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
  //                    todoImage.loadInBackground();
   //                    return;


                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

and the other (Detail information) class code

```
protected TextView txtName;
protected TextView txtType;
protected TextView txtAddr;
protected TextView txtDate;
String date;
String address;
String name1;
String type;
String todoImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_booking);
    init26();
    init30();

    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView67);

    txtType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView69);

    txtAddr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView73);

    txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView70);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

 //        intent.putExtra("Logo", todoImage.getParseFile());

    name1 = intent.getStringExtra("Name");

    type = intent.getStringExtra("Type");

    address = intent.getStringExtra("Address");

    date = intent.getStringExtra("Date");

    txtName.setText(name1);
    txtType.setText(type);
    txtAddr.setText(address);
    txtDate.setText(date);
```

My adapter class

```
class CustomAdapter3 extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> {

public CustomAdapter3(Context context) {

    super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

        public ParseQuery create() {
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Events");

/* query.whereEqualTo("Name", true);*/

            return query;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.events, null);
    }
    super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

    ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon5);
    ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("Logo");
    if (imageFile != null) {
        todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
        todoImage.loadInBackground();

        ParseImageView todoImage1 = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon1);
        ParseFile imageFile1 = object.getParseFile("Logo");
        if (imageFile1 != null) {
            todoImage1.setParseFile(imageFile1);
            todoImage1.loadInBackground();

        }
        TextView txtDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        txtDate.setText(object.getDate("Date").toString());

        TextView txtname1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView95);
        txtname1.setText(object.getString("Name"));

        TextView txtType1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        txtType1.setText(object.getString("Type"));
    }
    return v;
```

Comment: What's the problem actually?

Comment: Reaz Murshed  it does not display the image in the next activity, i had to comment it out. it only displays the information not the picture with.

Comment: Please add code for the adapter that you have

Comment: Vulovic Vukasin added the adapter class